# map directive in nginx work only in first variant

Tags: nginx

I try to use map directive.
I have 2 vars and if first var exist set it to new var, or if only second var exist, set it to new var.
My config:

```
map "$arg_arg1:$cookie_1" $new_var {
    "~^.*:" $arg_arg1;
    "~:.*$" $cookie_1;
    default "new";
}
```

Work only in first situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sequence `.*` also matches zero characters, so your first regex matches any string containing a `:`, including those that begin with a `:`.

Use `^.+:` to guarantee at least one character before the `:` or just `.:` (as the anchor is not really necessary).

If the cookie value may contain a `:`, you may want to use `^[^:]+:` instead.

Answer (score 0):

My working config:

```
map "$cookie_1:$arg_arg1" $new_var {
    default "new";
    "~:.*$" $arg_arg1;
    "~*^.*:$" $cookie_1;
}
```